# Getting Maven to Recognize Local Docker Containers

Tags: java, docker, maven

I'm downloaded my company's code repositories to create a local development environment. We're using Docker containers. I'm running a Mac using the Monterey OS with zsh. Plus, we're using maven and I have 3.8.4 installed on my machine.

I cannot get maven to recognize my local repository. I goes to the network repository that I downloaded from and can't find it and gives errors.

At this point, I've done quite a few things hoping they'll fix the problem, so far no luck. I added  C:/Users/mydirectory/.m2/repository to my settings.xml in my maven repository directory.

I can't remember some of the other things I've checked and changed. Yet I can't get maven to use my local downloads. It seems to build the parent but nothing else, and gives messages that it can't resolve and it is definitely looking at the network when it gives me the errors.

It says the POM is missing for the network items. I do have my POM in my parent directory. As a subdirectory, I have my docker-scripts. I have been just manually running the commands, at this point, trying to figure out where my issue is at.

Any suggestions? I want to just use direct path as much as possible, hoping that forces most commands to go where I want them to.

Comment: If you are on a Mac this: `C:/Users/mydirectory/.m2/repository` is simply wrong because the Mac does not have `C:` you should instead use `/Users/...` apart from that you should not add that because that is the default so don't configure it if you don't need to...

Comment: My apologies on that. I'm primarily a Windows user and when I wrote this, threw the C: in out of habit. I don't actually have that in my files on my Mac. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

After spending way too much time looking at this, had overlooked a typo in a path that I just noticed. Now, it's working.

Comment: Might not be an useful question and answer. Just a typo.